# SDE for 3D Bessel bridge

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

The SDE for a Bessel-3D bridge between $(x,t) = (0,0)$ and $(x,t)=(0,T)$ (starts and ends at the origin) is given by
$$dX_t = \left(\frac{1}{X_t}-\frac{X_t}{T-t}\right)dt + dB_t$$
where $B_t$ is a Gaussian process.
Now I have the following SDE:
$$dX_t = \left(\frac{1}{X_t}-\frac{X_t}{T-t}+a\right)dt + dB_t$$
where $a$ is a constant.

Could I interpret the later as a SDE for a Bessel-3D bridge? How can I transform from the later SDE to the former?

Comment: You could use a Radon-Nikodym derivative to Girsanov transform the $B_t+at$ into a BM without drift. Since the two probability measures share the same null sets they agree on what is an almost sure property. This applies to the fact that $X_T=0$. In short: the Bessel bridge stays a bridge. How you call/interpret this second SDE then is up to you.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your comment. Indeed I am not familiar with the stochastic analysis. Do you know any document on this problem, say for beginner?

Comment: For Bessel bridge I don't know a document. Standard stochastic analysis texts are by Oksendal, Karatzas & Shreve, Protter and many more. It is a matter of taste what you will like best.